# Combining the effects of two moduli

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

If I have:

$((x \bmod m_1) \bmod m_2) = z$

With $x,m_1,m_2$ given positive integers, is there some $y$ such that

$x \bmod y = z$

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "mod". If you mean the function that returns a specific integer (so mod $m$ returns an integer between 0 and $m-1$), then no - it would depend a lot on the relative sizes of $m_1$ and $m_2$. If you mean the function that returns an equivalence class of integers, then the statement isn't really well-defined, but it's sort of consistent to take $y=\gcd(m_1,m_2)$.

Comment: @GregMartin What I mean is that if I have $x$ and then take the remainder when dividing by $m_1$, and then take the remainder of that when dividing by $m_2$, it gives some integer $z$. However I want the integer $y$ such that when I divide $x$ by $y$ and take the remainder, I get $z$ (so the modulus that *mimics* the effect of doing the double-modulus operation).

Comment: Right, in that case the answer is almost surely going to be "no", at least for the vast majority of  $(m_1,m_2)$.

Answer (score -1):

$x\geq z$.

If $x=z$, then $m_1,m_2>z$, so you can take $y=m_1$.

If $x>z$, then you can take $y=x-z$.